# How to insert lambda (λ) symbol with IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I want to use a keyboard shortcut to insert the λ sign in IntelliJ.
Jetbrains employee Hadi Hariri explains in this [video](https://youtu.be/1ta8fTXKb5U?t=768) at 12:48 that you can insert the lambda symbol by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Hadi has the following code:

```
fun higherOrderFunction(f: (Int, Int) -> Int) {}
```

Then he marks the f character and I believe he type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

For Hadi, that results in:

```
fun higherOrderFunction(λ: (Int, Int) -> Int) {}
```

For me, it results in selecting the File menu.

How can I make IntelliJ replace the f with λ?

**Update:** Some people believe this is a duplicate, but I'm aware of that other question and that doesn't answer my question. The other question ask how to use Greek letters, I ask how IntelliJ can convert the character f into λ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write lambda letter (λ) in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047246/is-it-possible-to-write-lambda-letter-%ce%bb-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: While it is possible to use UNICODE characters in your code, I'd stick to basic ASCII characters as you're just introducing problems for people that will try to read (and edit) your codebase in the future.

Comment: @Pawel: I like your suggestion! It doesn't look as nice, but I guess it is the best and safest option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He uses a simple "Live Templates" (Preferences... -> Live Templates), triggered by the ƒ symbol (alt-F on a Mac) as you can see in the "Abbreviation" text-field.

[image: Live template in IntelliJ]

Comment: It's not the exact same solution. He uses <Alt>, while your suggestion does not support that. Your solutions is excellent though, and solves my problem!

Comment: no no :-)
It's not my solution, it's the way Hadi put a lambda symbol.
The template is triggered by the ƒ symbol (alt-F on the Mac) that you can see in the Abbreviation field in the Screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I guess it's a difference on shurtcuts between Linux and OS-X